# YDN-DB key Generator TypeScript

Tags: typescript, ydn-db

I want to create a databease schema using the TypeScript. It's pretty simple, but I can't, or don't know how, there to define the key generator.
In the User Guide, for example, such a code snippet(using JavaScript):

```
var schema = {
  ...
indexes: [
  {
    name: 'name', // index for case in-sensitive sorting
    generator: function(obj) {
      var name = obj.first + ' ' + obj.last;
      return name.toLowerCase();
    }
  }
],
```

Can I define this generator using the library **ydn.db-1.0.ts** (downloaded from the YDN-DB server) or **ydn-db.d.ts**(downloaded from DefinitelyTyped)?

For example I wrote this ts file:

```
/// <reference path="typings/ydn-db/ydn-db.d.ts" />
module YdnDbTest
{
  module DatabaseHelper
  {
    interface Place
    {
      Name: string;
      Location: string;
    }

    var AppDbSchema: DatabaseSchemaJson =
    {
      stores:
      [
        {
          name: "AppDbStore",
          keyPath: "Name",
          indexes:
          [
            {
              name: "idxLocation",
              keyPath: "Location",
              unique: true,
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
   }
 }
```

, and I would like for the Location wrote a generator. I would like to write something like:

```
        ...
        indexes:
        [
          {
            name: "idxLocation",
            generator: (record: Place): string => 
            { return record.Location.toLowerCase() },
            unique: true,
          }
        ]
        ...
```

Like I wrote generator for master key(Name), but it probably is not possible.

Comment: `ydn.db-1.0.ts` contains only a list of definitions, not the source code. So you still have to load `ydn.db-is-core-qry.js` file.

Comment: ydn.db-1.0.ts is the definition file, which should I use for writing the TypeScript code. I believe that file ydn.db-is-core-qry.js at this moment I don't need.

Comment: Yes, you should add to your TypeScript code at the top of a file `///<reference path="relative/path/to/ydn.db-1.0.ts" />` to load those TypeScript definitions and then you can use types defined in the file. However, you still need to reference the `.js` file at some point otherwise it won't work in your browser.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but I believe that it is not related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be solved using **ydn-db.d.ts**(from DefinitelyTyped). Library **ydn.db-1.0.ts** is broken(duplicate definition, instead of boolean bool is mentioned, etc.). In the case of the library **ydn-db.d.ts**(from DefinitelyTyped) the generator is overlooked. Using extension of the  IndexSchemaJson interface I can to write this code, including the generator:

```
/// <reference path="typings/ydn-db/ydn-db.d.ts" />
module YdnDbTest
{
  module DatabaseHelper
  {
    interface Place
    {
      Name: string;
      Location: string;
    }

    interface IndexSchemaJsonB extends IndexSchemaJson
    {
      generator?: (row: any) => any;
    }

    var AppDatabaseSchema: DatabaseSchemaJson =
    {
      stores:
      [
        {
          name: "StoreA",
          keyPath: "Name",
          indexes:
          [
            <IndexSchemaJsonB>
            {
              name: "idxLocation",
              keyPath: "Location",
              generator: (row: Place): string =>
                { return row.Location.toLocaleUpperCase(); }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
   }    
 }
```

}